# Animating UIButton background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, animation

Is there a way to animate a UIButton background image view with a set of images?

I've managed to do so with the imageView property, but couldn't find an equivalent background property.

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a buttons backround image, or text for that matter - you need to change it for the particular UIControlState... i.e Highlighted, Selected, Disabled

Use

`- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state`

I'm not sure if you can animate them, I've never tried. If you can't animate them, then you could put a UIImageView behind a transparent button and animate the images in that instead - just a thought.

Comment: I've put a UIImageView behind a transparent button. A little hacky, but what can I say - that worked! 10x

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I did (inside a UIButton subclass):

Set the button images, like regular:

```
[self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pressed"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Override highlighted:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
     [UIView transitionWithView:self duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
         [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
     } completion:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution

Answer (score 1):

You can animate an `UIButton` the way you animate an `UIImageView` like this...

```
-(void) addAnimationToButton:(UIButton*) button{
    UIImageView* animationView = [button imageView];
    NSArray* animations=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite2.png"],
                         //and so on if you need more
                         nil];
    CGFloat animationDuration = 2.0;
    [animationView setAnimationImages:animations];
    [animationView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [animationView setAnimationRepeatCount:0]; //0 is infinite
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
[self addAnimationToButton:yourButton];
[[yourButton imageView] startAnimating]; //or stopAnimating
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Use NSTimer ,

NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.00 target:self selector:@selector(changeImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

then, method is as follows,

```
- (void)changeImage
 {

           static int counter = 0;

           if([bannerArray count] == counter)
            {
                   counter = 0;
            }
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bannerArray[counter]]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

          counter++;
}
```

It worked for me. But adding animation like flip etc need to figure out. Hope this also one way to help your need.