# Animation (may be flip animation) on button image change on tab

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton, flip

Is there a way I can put animation (may be flip animation) on button image change on tab?

I know one way of doing it is with UIView instead of UIButton. Can it be done on UIButton?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Its working perfect according to your requirement:

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:btn duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedicon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }   completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

check the first answer to this question, might be what you are looking for
[Animating UIButton background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872972/animating-uibutton-background-image)

Answer (score 0):

old question, but here's how I did something similar. It's not flipping but fading in and out, which works well for me since my button has no background  (if it did, you'd see the background image fading out and back in, would look odd; and hey, the trend is now for background-less buttons ;-) )...

Anyway, here's what I did:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2f animations:^{
        _accessoryButton.alpha = 0.f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_accessoryButton setImage:newIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.2f animations:^{
                _accessoryButton.alpha = 1.f;
        }];
    }];
```

So I'm making the button fully transparent, changing the icon, and fading the button back in again...

I thought I'd be able to animate the opacity of the _accessoryButton.imageView but this doesn't work for some reason